Kustomize: apply patch results in error "add operation does not apply: doc is missing path"
I am trying to do a kustomize patch to an existing Helm deployment via a CI/CD pipeline. The CI pipeline is failing kustomize checks with error:
error: accumulating components: accumulateDirectory:
"recursed accumulation of path
'/runner/_work/ops-infra/ops-infra/current/components/mimir-prod/alertmanager/ops':
add operation does not apply: doc is missing path:
\"/spec/values/alertmanager/fallbackConfig/receivers/-\":
missing value`

The patch is defined in receivers-patch.yaml as follows:
- op: add
 path: /spec/chart/spec/values/alertmanager/fallbackConfig/receivers/-
  value:
    name: 'slack_receiver'
    slack_configs:
      - channel: "#ops"
        send_resolved: true
        slack_api_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/Txxxxx"

This patch adds a new "receiver" entry to the Mimir AlertManager Helm deployment. The patch is applied in kustomization.yaml file as:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
patches:
  - path: receivers-patch.yaml
    target:
      kind: HelmRelease
      name: mimir-prod

The deployment on which the patch is being applied is defined as below:
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta2
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: mimir-prod
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  ...
  ...
  values:
    alertmanager:
      fallbackConfig: |
        global:
          pagerduty_url: https://events.pagerduty.com/v2/enqueue
          resolve_timeout: 5m
        receivers:
          - name: 'null'
        route:
          group_by: ['alertname']
          group_interval: 5m
          group_wait: 30s
          receiver: 'null'

If the patch is successful this Helm deployment will look something like this:
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta2
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: mimir-prod
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  ...
  ...
  values:
    alertmanager:
      fallbackConfig: |
        global:
          pagerduty_url: https://events.pagerduty.com/v2/enqueue
          resolve_timeout: 5m
        receivers:
          - name: 'null'
          - name: 'slack_receiver'
            slack_configs:
              - channel: "#ops"
                send_resolved: true
                slack_api_url: "https://..."
        route:
          group_by: ['alertname']
          group_interval: 5m
          group_wait: 30s
          receiver: 'null'

I have looked at other questions here of similar nature but I cant quite find a match to my issue.
What am I doing wrong?

is the - at the end of the path necessary? I think what you are looking for is 0

same error, even afetr adding replacing with a 0 : "add operation does not apply: doc is missing path: "/spec/values/alertmanager/fallbackConfig/receivers/0": missing value"

@Bog see the update to the question. I think its  "-" instead of a "0"

Your problem is that the thing you are trying to patch is actually a string rather than a YAML object. Take a closer look at your HelmRelease manifest:
values:
  alertmanager:
    fallbackConfig: |
      global:
        pagerduty_url: https://events.pagerduty.com/v2/enqueue
        resolve_timeout: 5m
      receivers:
        - name: 'null'
        - name: 'slack_receiver'
          slack_configs:
            - channel: "#ops"
              send_resolved: true
              slack_api_url: "https://..."

The value of spec.chart.spec.values.alertmanager.fallbackConfig is a string. The | character is the YAML literal block quoting operator; see https://yaml-multiline.info/ for additional information.
You can't apply a Kustomize patch to the content of fallbackConfig because it's not a YAML object. You could only replace the entire value with a new one. E.g., this would work...
- op: replace
  path: /spec/chart/spec/values/alertmanager/fallbackConfig
  value: |
    receivers:
      name: 'slack_receiver'
      slack_configs:
        - channel: "#ops"
          send_resolved: true
          slack_api_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/Txxxxx"

...but that's not what you want. You would end up with:
spec:
  chart:
    spec:
      values:
        alertmanager:
          fallbackConfig: |
            receivers:
              name: 'slack_receiver'
              slack_configs:
                - channel: "#ops"
                  send_resolved: true
                  slack_api_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/Txxxxx"

